# Is this normal memory behaviour?

Tags: php, memory

i have a php script that processes large XML files, and saves data from them into a database. I use several classes, to process, and store the data in the PHP script, before saving to the database, and read in the XML, node by node, to preserve memory. Basicaly, a loop in my file looks like this:

```
while ($Reader->read()) {
        $parsed++;
        if (time() >= $nexttick) {
            $current=microtime(true)-$ses_start;
            $eta=(($this->NumberOfAds-$parsed)*$current)/$parsed;
            $nexttick=time()+3;
            $mem_usage=memory_get_usage();

            echo "Parsed $parsed @ $current secs \t | ";
            echo " (mem_usage: " . $mem_usage . " \t | ";
            echo "ETA: $eta secs\n";
        }

        $node=$Reader->getNode();
        // OMMITED PART: $node is an array, I make some processing, and check if everything exists in the array that I need in the following section

        $Ad=new Ad($node); // creating an Ad object from the node

        // OMMITED PART: Making some additional SQL queries, to check the integrity of the data, before uploading it to the database


        if (!$Ad->update()) {
            //add wasn't inserted succesfully, saving a row in a second database table, to log this information
        } else {
            //add succesfully inserted, saving a row in a second database table, to log this information
        }
}
```

You notice, that the first part of the loop, is a little output tool, that outputs the progress of the file, every 3 seconds, and also outputs the memory usage of the script. I need that because I ran into a memory problem, the last time I was trying to upload a file, and wanted to figure out, what's eating away the memory.

The output of this script looked something like this when I ran it:

> Parsed 15 @ 2.0869598388672 secs         |  (mem_usage: 1569552          | ETA: 1389.2195994059 secs
>   Parsed 30 @ 5.2812438011169 secs         |  (mem_usage: 1903632          | ETA: 1755.1333565712 secs
>   Parsed 38 @ 8.4330480098724 secs         |  (mem_usage: 2077744          | ETA: 2210.7901124829 secs
>   Parsed 49 @ 11.377414941788 secs         |  (mem_usage: 2428624          | ETA: 2310.5440017496 secs
>   Parsed 59 @ 14.204828023911 secs         |  (mem_usage: 2649136          | ETA: 2393.3931421304 secs
>   Parsed 69 @ 17.032008886337 secs         |  (mem_usage: 2831408          | ETA: 2451.3750760901 secs
>   Parsed 79 @ 20.359696865082 secs         |  (mem_usage: 2968656          | ETA: 2556.8171214997 secs
>   Parsed 87 @ 23.053930997849 secs         |  (mem_usage: 3102360          | ETA: 2626.8231951916 secs
>   Parsed 98 @ 26.148546934128 secs         |  (mem_usage: 3285096          | ETA: 2642.0705279769 secs
>   Parsed 107 @ 29.092607021332 secs        |  (mem_usage: 3431944          | ETA: 2689.8426286172 secs

Now, I know for certainty, that in my `MySQL` object, I have a runtime cache, which stores the results of some basic select queries in an array, for quick access later. This is the only variable in the script (that I know of), which increases in size throughout the whole script, so I tried turning of this option. The memory usage dropped, but only by a tiny bit, and it was still rising throughout the whole script.

My questions are the following:

1. Is the slow rising of the memory usage throughout a long running script a normal behaviour in php, or I should search through the whole code, and try to find out what is eating up my memory?
2. I know that by using `unset()` on a variable, I can free up the space it takes away from the memory, but do I need to use `unset()` even if I am overwriting the same variable throughout the whole file?

*A slight rephrasing of my second question with an example:*

Are the following two code blocks produce the same result regarding memory usage, or if not, which one is more optimal?

*BLOCK1*

```
 $var = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);
 $var = str_repeat("Good bye", 4242);
```

*BLOCK2*

```
 $var = str_repeat("Hello", 4242);
 unset($var);
 $var = str_repeat("Good bye", 4242);
```

Comment: Block1 and Block2 will be identical memory usage, but block2 will be slower because of the unsetting and recreating of $var

Comment: `slow rising of the memory usage throughout a long running script` is possible, but `slow rising of the memory usage throughout a long running script` inside a loop is rare unless the loop is building an array or similar.... it looks like something inside your loop is consuming memory and not releasing it

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I was affraid of. In this case I will need to debug one by one, each function that the loop uses:|

Comment: Tools like blackfire.io or xdebug can help with that process

Answer (score 0):

If you install the xdebug module on your development machine, you can get it to do a function trace - and that will show memory usage for each line - https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

That'll probably help you identify where the space is going up - you can then try to unset($var) etc and see if it makes any difference.